# IndexError: list index out of range Titanium Studio

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, osx-mavericks

When attempting to build a new Titanium Studio project on OS X Mavericks I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Kyle/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.0.1.GA2/iphone/builder.py", line 1334, in main
    cleanup_app_logfiles(ti, log_id, iphone_version)
  File "/Users/Kyle/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.0.1.GA2/iphone/builder.py", line 508, in cleanup_app_logfiles
    if is_indexing_enabled(tiapp, simulator_dir):
  File "/Users/Kyle/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.0.1.GA2/iphone/builder.py", line 411, in is_indexing_enabled
    status = lines[i+1].strip('\t.')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Titanium Studio, build: 3.1.1.201306112235**

**Xcode: Version 4.6.3**

Answer (score 1):

I got the following from Appcelerator developer forum. Please check it

> The problem was that the IOS SDK wasn't installed since I installed
>   XCode from the MacOSX Installation CD.
>
> If you want to know if that is your problem run this in the console
>
> `xcodebuild -showsdks`
>
> you should see a listing for IOS SDKs

Reference links :

1. [iPhone / iPad simulator don't run - list index out of range](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/149028/iphone--ipad-simulator-dont-run---list-index-out-of-range)
2. [Problem running KitchenSink on a fresh install](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/118264/problem-running-kitchensink-on-a-fresh-install)